# JScript is crashing with a very poor reason given

Tags: jscript, wsh, windows-scripting

I have the following code which works should theoretically work well:

```
var arg = WScript.arguments(0);
alert(arg.toString);
```

So when I run it in CMD, like this:
`hello_world.js "Sup"`

It'll get a runtime error immediately at line 2 with the reason being:
`Object expected`

But these docs say the alert function expects a string argument:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp

And actually.... it gets worse.

This will result in the same crash with the same runtime:

`alert("ummm wtf...");`

Is Microsoft JScript just useless or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Jscript is case sensitive .
Try with:

```
   WScript.Echo(WScript.Arguments.Item(0));
```

In WSH there's no alert , and you need to use `WScript.Echo`

you can call the script like this `cscript /e:jscript /nologo script.js`
or `wscript /e:jscript /nologo script.js`  .The first will output the messages in the console the second with pop-ups.

If you need to use alert you'll need MSHTA - http://www.brivers.com/resume/scripts/tutorial-hta.php